# nosql dynamic fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb, arangodb, nosql

I'm writing a rails application that has a user document which has about 20 different attributes. Each time an attribute is updated, I need to store it in a transactions document which will have who changed, which attribute was changed and the old value and new value of the attribute.

Does it make sense to have a separate document to store transactions? or should I use a noSQL DB like CouchDB which supports versioning by default and then I don't have to worry about creating a transactions document.

If I do decide to create a transaction document, then the key of the document will be dynamic.

When I need to pull history, I can pull out all versions of a document and dynamically figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I would not store all transactions for a given user in a single document. This document will become very large and it may begin to take a up a lot of memory when you have to bring it into memory. It might also be difficult to query on various transactions (i.e. find all transactions for a given user that modified the name attribute).

Answer (score 0):

The Versioning in CouchDB and similar NoSQL databases is a little bit misleading, and I tapped into the same mistake as you just did before. Versioning simply means - optimistic concurrency. This means that if you want to update a document, you need to provide the old version number with it, to be sure that nothing has been overwritten. So when you get a document and in the meanwhile someone else changes it, your version number is out of date (or out of sync) and you need to read it again and apply the required changes before submitting it to the database. Also some NoSQL stores allow you to ignore this versioning, while others (like CouchDB) enforce it.

Back to topic - Versioning won’t do what you want, you are rather looking for a log store with write often, read seldom (as I assume, you won’t read the history that often). In that case Cassandra is perfect for this, if you require a high throughput, but any other NoSQL or SQL DB might do the job as well, depending on your performance requirements.